# Proof of property of intersection of two ellipses

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Consider 3 collinear points $A$, $B$, and $C$, where $B$ is between $A$ and $C$. Draw two ellipses, one with foci at $A$ and $B$ going through $C$ and another with foci at $B$ and $C$ going through $A$. Suppose the two intersection points of the ellipses are $P$ and $Q$. Prove that
$$\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\angle PBC\right)=\frac{AB}{BC}$$

I tried letting the common focus, $B$, be the origin, and let $A=(-x_0, 0)$ and $B=(x_1, 0)$. Then the equations of the ellipses are:

$$\sqrt{(x+x_0)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2x_1+x_0$$
$$\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2x_0+x_1$$

I thought about subtracting and squaring, or using algebra to find the solution, but I am hoping there is a nicer solution, maybe using the focal reflective property of ellipses.

Geogebra: https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/vxqtzdhy

Comment: I don’t think that trying to bash it out directly from the equations of the ellipses is the way to go. The solutions to the system get ugly fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the cosine rule to triangles $CBP$ and $ABP$, setting $\alpha=\angle PBC$, $a=AB$, $b=BC$, $x=BP$:
$$
(2a+b-x)^2=b^2+x^2-2bx\cos\alpha\\
(a+2b-x)^2=a^2+x^2+2ax\cos\alpha\\
$$
Terms in $x^2$ cancel out and we are left with a linear system of equations in $x$ and $\cos\alpha$, which can be solved to yield:
$$
\cos\alpha={b^2-a^2\over b^2+a^2},
$$
which is the same as $\displaystyle\tan{\alpha\over2}={a\over b}$.